# Is this flagging behavior expected?

Tags: support, flags, downvotes, low-quality-posts, community-user

I'm not sure why I did it, but I played a little around with flags the last days and found some behavior I think is not or should not be expected.

When you

1. Flag a question as 'very low quality'
2. Edit the question

Your flag will be found helpful immediately and the question gets a downvote - I guess the community user does this.

Should not the flag only have an effect if there is a certain amount of users who flagged it/really found it helpful? And where does the downvote really come from?

Comment: Concrete examples please. There's no obvious conjunction for the events you mention. IMHO these occur just by chance.

Comment: Try it, works all the time with those two steps. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: I thought so, too. But all I mentioned happens within seconds after the edit, so I doubt a moderator did some action that fast.

Comment: I just tested on this question and yes, seems to work exactly like OP says it does.

Comment: reported on meta.SE 2 years ago https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187244/edited-postlowqualityauto-still-get-a-downvote

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Should a user be able to flag a question as VLQ and then immediately mark it helpful by making an edit? No, we should probably fix that.

As far as the downvote: the Community user casts an implicit downvote on the post whenever a VLQ flag gets marked as helpful (regardless of whether it was caused by an edit). Recently, we changed this so that if someone comes along and upvotes the post sometime after that downvote was cast, the Community user will automatically withdraw its downvote on the post, within about an hour, whenever the script runs (again, regardless of whether it was caused by an edit).

In fact, the downvote caused by the experiment on your question here was already withdrawn by the Community user.

Comment: I flagged your answer as NAA, then edited it, and it didn't immediately resolve it as helpful. Thought it would. Glad it doesn't though. Thanks for declining it.

Comment: I'm not the one that declined it, but only VLQ flags get dismissed automatically by edits. NAA flags are not affected by it. (As well, helpful NAA flags do not add an implicit downvote either.)

Comment: So... that means that you can temporarily double-downvote a post?

Comment: @Siguza Well, you've always been able to do that with spam/offensive flags. The downvotes just get reversed much more quickly (immediate effect when it gets declined) and you have to get at least five other people to agree with you to get it automatically marked helpful.